# Uniswap: How to read token price with API

Tags: php, blockchain, ethereum, erc20

In my PHP code (or Javascript) I would like to read erc20 (Ethereum) token price from Uniswap - it is trading there. I cannot find any API call to return me the price.

I am looking to get price for this token:
VIRGIN TOKEN: 0x1381F369D9D5df87a1A04Ed856C9dbc90f5DB2fA

How can I do it?

Comment: Documentation for how to do this for uniswap v2 is at https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/2.0.0/guides/pricing.

Answer (score 9):

You can query [Uniswap data](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/API/overview/) on [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/docs/introduction#what-the-graph-is) using [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).

One way is to query `token` directly:

```
{
  token(id: "0x1381f369d9d5df87a1a04ed856c9dbc90f5db2fa") {
    derivedETH
  }
}
```

... where `derivedETH` is ETH price.

Another is to query pair (by pair `id` or, in this example, using token `id`'s):

```
{
  pairs(where: { token0: "0x1381f369d9d5df87a1a04ed856c9dbc90f5db2fa" token1: "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2" }) {
    token0Price
    token1Price
  }
}
```

... where `token0Price` and `token1Price` are prices of tokens relative to each other (VRGN\WETH).

You can play with these in [sandbox](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2?query=Example%20query) or you might need a [client](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql-clients/).

Alternatively, to keep things simple, you can do request directly, like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": "{ token(id: \"0x1381f369d9d5df87a1a04ed856c9dbc90f5db2fa\") { derivedETH } }"}' https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2
```

... to get:

```
{"data":{"token":{"derivedETH":"0.0004465905539042863338157407540331524"}}}
```

Comment: This looks like some 3rd party api. Is there a way to query a token on the polygon mainnet via uniswap api?

Comment: We can add `bundle(id: "1") { ethPrice }` to the same query for ETH price in USD, then calculate token price in USD.